# How can I interact with the user inside a CasperJS/PhantomJS script?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Imagine a script like

```
system = require "system"

system.stdout.write "What's your name? "
name = system.stdin.readLine()
system.stdout.writeLine "Hello, #{name}"
```

To be run via

```
casperjs name.coffee
```

---

I'd like to be able to interact with the user in the terminal used to run the script, but I get stuck in the readLine() call.

Answer (score 2):

As [GarethOwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144486/garethowen) pointed out, it is indeed possible.
Here is a very basic CasperJS implementation of the Unix command `cat`:

```
var system = require('system'),
    casper = require('casper').create();
while (!system.stdin.atEnd()) {
    var line = system.stdin.readLine();
    casper.log(line);
}
casper.exit();
```

Note that this module is mostly implemented in C++:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/system.h

And that `stdin` / `stdout` / `stderr` are instances of the PhantomJs class `File` :
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/filesystem.h

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, phantomJS can communicate with standard input. See this example:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/stdin-stdout-stderr.js

Documentation regarding inter-process communication is here:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Inter-Process-Communication

But I've never tried it myself.

Comment: Inter Process Communication is not available. Do we have any other resources to communicate with phantomjs?